# How can I parse a multi-line command output in bash?

Tags: text-processing

I have a command that outputs the following:

```
Some text here
    1,3456: "Descr 1"
    2,7891: "Descr 2"
    3,0976: "Descr 3"

Some other random text here
```

I want to write a bash script that parses out the first column and stores the values somewhere, so I can present the options to an end user.

I can use awk to get the first column, but because of that random text at the end ("Some other random text here"), it's messing up my awk command.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

VERSIONS=`/usr/libexec/somebin -V`

OPTIONS=$VERSIONS | awk -F'[,]' '{print $1}'

while read -r line; do
   echo "... $line ..."
done <<< $OPTIONS
```

and all it does is print out:

```
Some text here
    1,3456: "Descr 1"
    2,7891: "Descr 2"
    3,0976: "Descr 3"

...  ...
```

But I wanted it to print out:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple command before the pipe in:

```
OPTIONS=$VERSIONS | awk -F'[,]' '{print $1}'
```

sets `OPTIONS` to `$VERSIONS`. Since there is no actual utility name there, the command is simply an assignment, and thus it produces no output. So nothing is piped to `awk`, and consequently `awk` does nothing. (And even if it did something, it wouldn't do it to `$OPTIONS`.

Even worse, the pipe ensures that both the command before and the command after are executed in subshells. So `OPTIONS` is not set in the shell which contains the compound command.

I presume that what you wanted was something like this:

```
OPTIONS=$(/usr/libexec/somebin -V | cut -f1 -d,)
```

or maybe

```
VERSIONS=$(/usr/libexec/somebin -V)
OPTIONS=$(echo "$VERSIONS" | cut -f1 -d,)
```

where the `cut` command does exactly the same thing as your invocation of `awk`.

But neither that nor your awk command will filter out the lines with "some text", so maybe you need an actual filter, perhaps something like this:

```
VERSIONS=$(/usr/libexec/somebin -V | grep ,)
OPTIONS=$(echo "$VERSIONS" | cut -f1 -d,)
```

Comment: Very clever to filter the lines that you really need with `grep ,`, I have incorporated this list-processing approach into my routine now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[,]' '/^[ ]/{print $1}'
```

Would only act on lines that begin with a space, thus skipping those without such. Another option might be to look for lines containing a comma, or a different regex if insidious tabs are used instead of spaces...

Answer (score 1):

you could do this with bash alone --

```
IFS=","; while read -r a b; do [[ $a =~ [0-9]+ ]] && echo $a; done < 1; unset IFS
1
2
3
```